# How to make this effect with ScrollView?

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin

I have a `ScrollView` that has its height and width set to `match_parent`. This `ScrollView` has a `RelativeLayout` with content. When the user scrolls the screen, this `RelativeLayout` covers the top of the screen. But the problem is that in this upper part of the screen, in addition to different views, there is a `close` button that should be clickable when it is visible, when the lower `RelativeLayout` covers it, it should be unclickable. The problem is that the `ScrollView` does not allow this button to be clicked. If we arrange the button in the `ScrollView` along the XML hierarchy, then it will also scroll, but I need the top views and this button to remain static.
Here is [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAPr9.jpg) of how it should be.

```
<carbon.widget.RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/cyan"
    tools:context=".OptionsActivity">

    <carbon.widget.Button
        android:id="@+id/close"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/close"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="21dp"
        app:carbon_elevation="0dp" />

    <com.xw.repo.widget.BounceScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:scrollbars="none">

        <carbon.widget.RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="110dp"
            android:fillViewport="true">

        <!-- content -->

        </carbon.widget.RelativeLayout>

    </com.xw.repo.widget.BounceScrollView>

</carbon.widget.RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `CollapsingToolbarLayout` with `NestedScrollView`